# How to plot figures side by side in plotly Dash?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, data-visualization

The following [link](https://community.plotly.com/t/two-graphs-side-by-side/5312) provides code to plot a chart in plotly side by side with html components. However, I'm looking for a similar functionality like [`plt.subplot`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html) of matplotlib. The following image, taken from [official documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html) of matplotlib is an example of the desired output.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

With [inset plots](https://plotly.com/python/v3/insets/) in plotly you can set two plots side by side, specifying a `domain` argument in the Layout component, that is,

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go

go.Layout(xaxis = dict(domain = [0.0, 0.45]),
          xaxis2 = dict(domain = [0.55, 1.0]),
         )
```

where you can adjust the position of the x-axis of the figure switching the values between 0 and 1. For a full example, see the section below.

### Example

As example to plot a **scatter plot** with a **bar graph** side by side,

```
# Set plotly in offline mode
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

# Simple Scatter plot
trace0 = go.Scatter(x = [10, 20, 30],
                    y = [40, 30, 20]
)

# Simple Bar chart
trace1 = go.Bar(x=['cat_1', 'cat_2', 'cat_3', 'cat_4'],
                y=[5, 27, 31, 48],

                xaxis='x2',
                yaxis='y2'
               )

# Data component 
data = [trace0, trace1]

# Layout component
layout = go.Layout(xaxis = dict(domain = [0.0, 0.45]),
                   xaxis2 = dict(domain = [0.55, 1.0]),
                   yaxis2 = dict(overlaying='y',
                                 anchor = 'free',
                                 position = 0.55
                                )

                  )

# Figure component
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

offline.iplot(fig)
```

outputs the following image. 
[image]